# Use ruby to remove a part of a string on each entry in an array where it exists

Tags: ruby

I have a list of file paths, for example

```
[
  'Useful',
  '../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Interesting',
  '../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Also/Interesting'
]
```

(I mention that they're file paths in case there is something that makes this task easier because they're files but they can be considered simply a set of strings some of which  may start with a particular string)

and I need to make this into a set of pairs so that I have the original list but also

```
[
  'Useful',
  'Interesting',
  'Also/Interesting'
]
```

I expected I'd be able to do this

```
'../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Interesting'.gsub!('../Some.Root.Directory/Path/', '')
```

or

```
'../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Interesting'.gsub!('\.\.\/Some\.Root\.Directory\/Path\/', '')
```

but neither of those replaces the provided string/pattern with an empty string...

So in irb

```
puts '../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Interesting'.gsub('\.\.\/Some\.Root\.Directory\/Path\/', '')
```

outputs

```
../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Interesting
```

and the desired output is

```
Interesting
```

How can I do this?

NB the path will be passed in so really I have

```
file_path.gsub!(removal_path, '')
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that'd be self-explanatory. I'll make it concrete :)

Comment: Why are you using `gsub!` instead of `sub!`? I don't understand what you are doing with it.

Comment: I don't ruby much so I may well not be using the right methods

Comment: If you want to retain the original array, why are you using `gsub!` instead of `gsub` (or `sub`, which makes more sense)?

Comment: I've fallen into the hole of trying to make the code example explain rather than simply showing my code. I've added an example that can be run in irb

Comment: The title is also misleading. Is it really an arbitrary part? Isn't it the beginning of the strings?

Comment: it's the beginning of some of them (right now) being removed based on the needs of the caller. i.e. some consumers might not need to remove that string. we gather the list for more than one purpose

Comment: So you want to say that some strings may match and some may not match, right? Still, is it always at the beginning of a string where a match should occur (i.e., not in the middle or the end of a string)?

Comment: yep, it's always the beginning of the string but not every string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get pairs of the original paths and the shortened ones, you can use `sub` in combination with `map`:

```
a = [
   '../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Interesting',
   '../Some.Root.Directory/Path/Also/Interesting'
]

b = a.map do |v| 
  [v, v.sub('../Some.Root.Directory/Path', '')] 
end

puts b
```

This will return an Array of arrays - each sub-array contains the original path plus the shortened one. As noted by @sawa - you can simply use `sub` instead of `gsub`, since you want to replace only a single occurrence.

Comment: Why use `gsub`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sawa You're right, gsub is not necessary here. Replaced with sub.

Comment: And for safety, it might be better to use a regex with `\A` before the path.

Comment: I'm certain I did that yesterday but clearly my brain was tired since it definitely works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are positive that strings start with `removal_path` you can do:

```
string[removal_path.size..-1]
```

to get the remaining part.

Comment: sorry, my example is misleading. not all of the strings start with that path (although I could add it where it doesn't exist :))